# Communicate with api server using nsis

Tags: nsis

I tried nsis for the first time.
You want to send a post to the api server using nsis.
I used the inetc module, the InetLoad module, and the nsJSON module
All communication is not possible.

Help me, I do not feel at all.

For example, if you have headers, data, and url, you know how to use the module. Please.

I am trying to communicate with the api server using inetc :: post
Pop Returns OK from $ 0.
However, if you look at the server logs, you will see a header check fail.
Why?

Comment: We need more information. Post parts of your log...

Comment: inetc::post /PASSWORD "http://cgapi.xxxxxxxx.co.kr/p/cAuth2/CPC_LOGIN" /HEADER "rflag: xxxxxxxxxPC" /CAPTION "{$\"PS$\":$\"CVTR603600xxxxxxxx$\", $\"PI$\": $\"$2$\", $\"PP$\": $\"$3$\", $\"AT$\": $\"P$\" }" $EXEDIR\post_reply.json /END

I am sending it this way.

request : Header check fail - Invalid Request!

server log = header = null

Comment: If so, * header = 1 / data = 2 / url = 3

inetc::post /header "1" /caption "2" /password "3" $EXEDIR\post_reply.json /END
I send it like this.

Comment: When uninstalling, it tries to get login information to the api server and delete it when it is the same as the value entered by the user.

Comment: rflag is not a valid HTTP header?